# How to write values with uncertainty and units with brackets: (339+-14) m/s

Tags: siunitx

This code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true,multi-part-units=single,list-units=repeat]{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\[\SI{339\pm14}{\meter\per\second}\]

\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

But I want

[image]

```
\[v_s= (339   \pm 14)\, \si{\meter\per\second}\]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From page 42 of the manual https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true,list-units=repeat,multi-part-units=brackets]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\[\SI{339\pm14}{\meter\per\second}, \SI{339}{\meter\per\second}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not an expert on that package but I guess the global option does not do any harm, anyway: Please **read the fine manual (RTFM).**

Comment: You may want to rewrite the answer so that `multi-part-units=brackets` *replaces* `multi-part-units=single` in the list of arguments of the `\usepackage{siunitx}`.

Comment: @Mico Indeed. Thank you very much. Didn't your answer utilized a different way to achieve the same effect? Why was it deleted? You were even faster than me.

Comment: I deleted my answer because your's is a *lot* better. :-)

Comment: @Mico I feel honored to read such a statement from you, Mico, a more experienced, more knowledgable, always friendly and helpful member of the community, and author of the great and useful package https://ctan.org/pkg/selnolig.